# Java serialisation with google apps not working

Tags: java, serialization, binary, deserialization

I have serialized(writeObject(o); close) complex object in on Windows with jdk6. Then I upload it to google apps engine, and code throws exception "StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 08" when I try to deserialize it(readObject()).

Is it possible to fix such problem or it unresolvable JDK serialization incompatibility?

Comment: can you give an example of what you are serializing and how you are reading it on app engine?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the classes you are allowed to use in Google App Engine.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html